# Getting all text nodes in xml using linq or xpath

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I'm trying to get all text nodes from any XML. So I need the code to be a bit dynamic.

The following are two of many different XMLs I need to process.

```
<questionset>

<!-- 1 -->
      <question id="1" returnOnIncorrect="false" vo="" img="">
         <![CDATA[
            ddddddddd?
         ]]>
    <!-- a -->
      <answer id="1" correct="0">
        <input>
          <![CDATA[
              eeeeeeeeee
          ]]>
        </input>
        <output>
          <![CDATA[
              iiiiiiiii.
          ]]>
        </output>
      </answer>
     </question>
</questionset>
```

Other XML

```
<xml>
  <content>
    <layout layoutId="0" copyFromId="0">
      <text indent="1" containerId="0">aaaaaaaa</text>
      <sound src="assets/SND_29c.mp3" />
      <img src="assets/IMG_29c.jpg" />
      <text indent="1" containerId="0">bbbbbbb</text>
      <sound src="assets/SND_29d.mp3" />
      <text indent="1" containerId="0">cccccccc</text>
    </layout>
  </content>
</xml>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to get all text nodes using XPath or Linq.

Have tried using XPath with "//text()" but this does not get the text inside CDATA nodes.

UPDATE 
**PreserveWhitespace is true**

Then I tried with Linq using the following query with no luck:

```
var xxml = XElement.Load(this.m_folder + "\\" + item.DisplayName);                
var query =
           from e in xxml.Descendants()
           where e.NodeType==XmlNodeType.CDATA
           select e;
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You *can* extract CDATA sections with XPath. You just can't refer directly to them as `text()`, but you can select the element that contains the CDATA section and get its string value. What I mean is `//output/text()` won't work, but `string(//output)` will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LINQ to XML and

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("file.xml");
IEnumerable<XText> textNodes = doc.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked using XPath `//text()`. I put both your XMLs in one file just to test it:

```
string xmlString = 
    "<questionset>\n" +
    "  <!-- 1 -->\n" +
    "  <question id=\"1\" returnOnIncorrect=\"false\" vo=\"\" img=\"\">\n" +
    "    <![CDATA[\n" +
    "      ddddddddd?\n" +
    "    ]]>\n" +
    "    <!-- a -->\n" +
    "    <answer id=\"1\" correct=\"0\">\n" +
    "      <input>\n" +
    "        <![CDATA[\n" +
    "          eeeeeeeeee\n" +
    "        ]]>\n" +
    "      </input>\n" +
    "      <output>\n" +
    "        <![CDATA[\n" +
    "          iiiiiiiii.\n" +
    "        ]]>\n" +
    "      </output>\n" +
    "    </answer>\n" +
    "  </question>\n" +
    "  <content>\n" +
    "    <layout layoutId=\"0\" copyFromId=\"0\">\n" +
    "      <text indent=\"1\" containerId=\"0\">aaaaaaaa</text>\n" +
    "      <sound src=\"assets/SND_29c.mp3\" />\n" +
    "      <img src=\"assets/IMG_29c.jpg\" />\n" +
    "      <text indent=\"1\" containerId=\"0\">bbbbbbb</text>\n" +
    "      <sound src=\"assets/SND_29d.mp3\" />\n" +
    "      <text indent=\"1\" containerId=\"0\">cccccccc</text>\n" +
    "    </layout>\n" +
    "  </content>\n" +
    "</questionset>";

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("//text()");

foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in nodes) {
    Console.WriteLine("<text>" + childrenNode.SelectSingleNode(".").Value.Trim() + "</text>");
}
```

This prints:

```
<text>ddddddddd?</text>
<text>eeeeeeeeee</text>
<text>iiiiiiiii.</text>
<text>aaaaaaaa</text>
<text>bbbbbbb</text>
<text>cccccccc</text>
```

(Using *Xamarin*, on *Mac OS 10.9*)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to add that I'm using PreserveWhitespace = true. Now CDATA is not showing anything. Do you know why?

Comment: I have no idea. Seems like the parser ignores CDATA sections completely when you turn that flag on. If you need that option on, you might consider using some API for *canonicalization* (C14) of your XML file prior to processing. That will convert your CDATA sections into text (and escape any tags that are inside it).